# python3.8 y firefox

Tags: python, firefox

ando teniendo un problema. Necesito usar python3.10 para un proyecto que usa cierto tipo de datos. Pero al desinstalar python3.8 tambien se desinstala firefox, y al instalar firefox se intala python3.8 , lo cual me resulta rarísimo. alguien sabe como resolverlo? es normal esto?

Comment: Puedes tener varias versiones de Python instaladas. Por ejemplo, en Linux traes Python 2.7 y 3.8. No necesitas desinstalar nada diria yo.

Comment: @CandidMoe eso de tener varias versiones puede traer confictos dificiles sobre todo para los novatos (un script se ejecuta en una versión mientras pip instala en otra). Además, lo que le está pasando me parece extraño... Sin embargo, tenes razón en que se puede tener varias versiones instaladas.